# Package 'youngtab' should be in Miktex, but I get an error

Tags: packages, miktex, texmaker

So I want to use the package `youngtab`, according to CTAN, this is already provided in MiKTeX, which I am using. However, when compiling with TeXmaker, I get the error that the package is not found.

I have no knowledge about the whole LaTeX package thing and don't know what to do, but I do need the package, its for an exam. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

PS: I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This package is part of MikTeX. It can be installed on two ways: on the fly, if you select this option in your installation or by help of MikTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Ok, two questions, what is 'pat' and how do I acces the Miktex package manager?

Comment: "pat" is wrongly typed "part". MikTeX Package Manager is part of MikTeX bundle. It is in the same place as other supporting managers (for update and settings, in lager you can select  "load missing packages on-the-fly"), where -- depends of your OS.

Comment: Then check the App menu.  There you will find all MiKTeX programs for updating, package managing, settings ...

Comment: Ow sorry, yea, I found the package manager, installed youngtab and it works. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. **It is the way to say "Thank You" here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 shows installed programs (like MiKTeX 2.9) on the App page.

Please click on the windows symbol in the task line, then go down and click on the following symbol (it will be shown if you move the mouse cursor down):

[image]

then the complite list of all installed apps is showed.  Usually you have now to go to the left side to find the programs to control MiKTeX:

[image]